# Facing issue when posting a large amount of data to ThingsBoard using Paho MQTT

Tags: thingsboard

I've recently encountered an issue while trying to post a substantial amount of data to ThingsBoard using the Paho MQTT client. The error message

```
Failed to process session update. Max session updates limit reached.
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue with the "Failed to process session update. Max session updates limit reached" error when using Paho MQTT to post a large amount of data to ThingsBoard? If so, what steps did you take to resolve it?

I also tried to change thingsboard fallowing settings in `/etc/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf`:

```
export NETTY_MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE=1095536000
export TB_SERVER_WS_DEFAULT_QUEUE_MESSAGES_PER_SESSION=1000000
export ACTORS_MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSION_PER_DEVICE=1000000
export MQTT_MSG_QUEUE_SIZE_PER_DEVICE_LIMIT=1000
export TB_QUEUE_PUBSUB_MAX_MESSAGES=10000
export TB_SERVER_WS_DYNAMIC_PAGE_LINK_REFRESH_POOL_SIZE=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a [rate limit defined in `WS_UPDATES_PER_SESSION`](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/b0a7466b2b40294047c337923d927817756db11c/application/src/main/java/org/thingsboard/server/controller/plugin/TbWebSocketHandler.java#L345C54-L352). `WS_UPDATES_PER_SESSION` is set [here](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/b0a7466b2b40294047c337923d927817756db11c/common/data/src/main/java/org/thingsboard/server/common/data/limit/LimitedApi.java#L32) and it seems to be set from the tenant configuration.

"*WS updates per session*" should be configurable on the tenant profile details:
[image: tb-tenant-profile-details]

Comment: I tied to increase rate limit, but still then posting a lot of data, these messages seems  show? I know this is different question, but maybe you know is some kind of solution for syncing large datasets with thing-board, when device is offline and then reconnects

Comment: Can you clarify if updating `WS_UPDATES_PER_SESSION` solved your particular issue and what are the other errors that are raised when you are syncing large datasets?

Comment: No, still with update values, I get  Max session updates limit reached errors.